# Distributing statements for a JDBC transaction in multiple methods

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions

I need to do a considerably long JDBC transaction. Can I distribute the statements required for the transaction in multiple methods, like this?

```
try {
    // ... Get connection
    // Start transaction
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    // In every one of these methods a series of statements is executed
    // All methods throw a SQLException which is caught here for rollback
    // Every method takes this connection as an argument
    method1(connection);
    method2(connection);
    // ...
    methodN(connection);
    // Commit all changes done inside the methods
    connection.commit();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    connection.rollback();
} finally {
    connection.setAutoCommit(true);
    connection.close();
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this *wouldn't* work?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the scope of the Statement objects inside the methods is related in any way. The Statements do not exist after a method returns, and I don't know how executed queries are "stored" as the program runs. Are they "tied" to the Connection object instead of the Statement object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with this. The important thing is to make sure you close the connection when you are done, which are you doing there. I would make sure that the code that opens the connection is in the same method where it closes it, because connection leaks can be really tough to track down.

As a side note, I like to use Spring's JDBC functionality. It manages connections for you and is really easy to use.
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

Comment: Thanks for the link! I may try using Spring.

Comment: I would second (and third) the Spring recommendation.  Why write boilerplate yourself?  They've done it beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

In a word: yes.

Incidentally long running transactions can be harmful. For example, [in SQL Server, they can cause the transaction log to fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366331.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Two things to correct:

Both the `rollback()` and `close()` methods on `java.sql.Connection` throw `SQLException`.  You should wrap both calls in try/catch blocks to ensure proper operation.  (In your case, the code won't even compile as written.)